# Why does "ShiftLeft" not trigger a keyUp-event while "ShiftRight" is held and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, html, events, keycode

Consider the following minimal setup:

```js
    function keyDown(event, element) {
        console.log("Down: " + event.code);
    }
    function keyUp(event, element) {
        console.log("Up: " + event.code);
    }
```

```html
    <input
        type="text"
        onkeyup="keyUp(event, this)"
        onkeydown="keyDown(event, this)"
    />
```

Now, when the input field is active the console will display a message every time a key was pressed, and every time a key was released, together with the key code of the key in question.

Pressing and releasing a single key will result in two messages:

`Down: KeyA`
`Up: KeyA`

Pressing and holding one key, then pressing and holding another key, then releasing the first key, then releasing the second key will result in 4 messages:

`Down: KeyA`
`Down: KeyB`
`Up: KeyA`
`Up: KeyB`

This is behaving as expected.
Now, for context, the "Shift" key actually has two key-codes, `ShiftRight` and `ShiftLeft` to differentiate between the left and right shift keys on most keyboards respectively. And now comes the interesting part:

Repeating the same two-button pattern as before, just with the two shift keys this time, results in the following output:

`Down: ShiftRight`
`Down: ShiftLeft`
`Up: ShiftLeft`

Even though I released the right shift key before I released the left, there was never a keyUp-event fired for it. The same shows if I do it the other way around, starting with `ShiftLeft`:

`Down: ShiftLeft`
`Down: ShiftRight`
`Up: ShiftRight`

At first I thought maybe that was simply how those special buttons that have multiple versions on the keyboard are treated, but it doesn't seem to be that simple. Both `ControlLeft` and `ControlRight` for example behave the same way as any other button. `Enter` and `NumpadEnter` on the other hand behave the same way as the two shifts are behaving, leaving out one keyUp-event every time.

What is the reason for this behavior? And is there a way to toggle it off?

Comment: "is there a way to toggle it off?" - could you explain what it is you are trying to do, exactly? I think the question is fine, but seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @chazsolo I'm basically just looking for a way that treats every key individually, and ensures that every pressed key that fires a keyDown-event also eventually fires a keyUp-event on release. It's not a direct problem I'm having with the code I'm writing right now, I just noticed this behaviour, and want to eliminate potential edge-cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a case of the browser helping against your will. After some investigation when running into this myself, I noticed that the `event.repeat` flag is set in a rather odd way.

From my experimentation is seems that the browser merges both shift keys together, but only for `keyup` events. Pressing the first key will emit a `keydown` event with the appropriate code and `event.repeat: false`. Pressing the other key emits the `keydown` event with its own code but `event.repeat: true`... even though it's a different key. At this point, the browser completely forgets they're separate keys.

Once you release one key... nothing happens. The browser still thinks 'shift' is held, so it just swallows the event entirely. In fact, you can press and release it multiple times but only get `keydown` events. Only once you release the second shift key will you get a single `keyup` event, with its respective code.

I'm not sure there's any way to stop this behavior. The event is simply not generated at all, and even cancelling/preventDefaulting the original shift press does not affect it.

This prevents you from properly recognizing the sequence of both shift keys to a single key, but you can still rely on `keyup` to recognize that *both* shift keys have been released, as that seems to be its condition for firing. If you are tracking individual keypresses, you can register a release of `ShiftLeft` as also a release of `ShiftRight`, and vice versa.